# Song picking system

Tags: c#, android, audio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do a song picking UI in my project. Everytime u click on a button in the game it sends int to this function. Is there a better way to structure this code so i don't have to write IF statements for every single song?

```
public void SongPick(int song)
{
    if (song == 0)
    {
        audioSource.clip = musicArray[0];    
    }
    if (song == 1)
    {
        audioSource.clip = musicArray[1];
    }
    if (song == 2)
    {
        audioSource.clip = musicArray[2];
    }

    audioSource.Play();
    string currentMusic = musicArray[song].name;
    songName.text = "PLAYING: " + currentMusic;
}
```

Comment: How about ``audioSource.clip = musicArray[song]``? Obviously you have to check before if the int is greater equals 0 and smaller than the length of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `song` always references the correct index in `musicArray` you definitely don't need an ever-growing if statement.

```
public void SongPick(int song) {
    if (song < musicArray.length) {
        audioSource.clip = musicArray[song];    
    }    
    audioSource.Play();
    string currentMusic = musicArray[song].name;
    songName.text = "PLAYING: " + currentMusic;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a check for any number less-equal zero.